# Subscribing inside a custom Async Validator is wrong?, slow performance should be expected?

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, angular-reactive-forms, angular-custom-validators

I have been looking lots of tutorials about implementing async validators to a reactive form in angular and i have a doubt with my following code.

```
  userNameAsyncValidator = (control: FormControl) =>
  new Observable((observer: Observer<ValidationErrors | null>) => {
    this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
      if((control.value !== this.user.userLogin) && users.find(user => user.userLogin === control.value)) {
        observer.next({ error: true, duplicated: true });
      }else {
        observer.next(null);
      }
      observer.complete();
    })
  });
```

Is this the best way to deal with this?, is a bad practice to subscribe from the observable inside de asyncValidator?

Comment: why would you subscribe inside an async validator? a validator should do exactly what it states `validate` it should be subscribing to anything, period. What you could do instead of subscribing in the validator is subscribe to the `valueChanged` event of your control and check if the validator failed - then do what you need to do.

Comment: @Bargros Thanks for your reply!, im really new with this so... pardon for some unlogic questions, If i dont get suscribed inside the validator, how do i get the list of users to search for the repeated username?, should i do it before the subscription ?.

Answer (score 0):

Your validator `validator.ts` or whatever the name of your file is:

```
// we wrap the validator in a function that we can pass the list of users
// when the validator is created, it caches the list of users
const userNameAsyncValidator = (users: User[]) => (control: FormControl) =>
  new Observable((observer: Observer<ValidationErrors | null>) => {
      if((control.value !== this.user.userLogin) && users.find(user => this.user.userLogin === control.value)) {
        observer.next({ error: true, duplicated: true });
      }else {
        observer.next(null);
      }
      observer.complete();
    })
  })
);
```

A couple of things to say about your validator:

- what happens if the control value is null?
- also do you need the validator to be an async validator?

Your component:

```
import { validator } from './validator';

 @Component({
  ...
 })
 class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   private destroy$ = new Subject();
   private userList: User[];

   public control = new FormControl(
     '', 
     // we pass the list of referenced users to generate our validator
     validator(this.users)
   );
    
   constructor(private userService: UserService) {}
  
   ngOnInit() {
     // subscribe here and fetch the list of users when the component is instantiated
     // and keep a reference
     this.userService
         .pipe( takeUntil(this.destroy$))
         .subscribe(users => this.userList = users)
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
     this.destroy.next();
     this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
   }
 }
```